# Accessing object of one class to see if it exists in another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have created a class `BankAccount` which stores the balance and the user list. I'm using a user list because a lot of users can be authorised to use a given bank account

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self,balance, users = None):
        self.balance = balance
        if users is None:
            self.users = []
    else:
        self.users = users

def withdraw(self,amount):
    if self.balance >= amount:
        self.balance -= amount

def deposit(self,amount):
    if amount >= 0:
        self.balance += amount


def balance(self):
    return self.balance


def access(user):
    ###This is where I am confused
```

I have another class in which I define what a user is:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, houseaddress):
        self.name = name
        self.houseaddress = houseaddress
```

I make objects `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` for class `User`:

```
user1 = User('Lilly', 'Sweet Valley, USA')
user2 = User('Jason', 'Melbourne, Australia')
user3 = User('Kevin','Santa Monica, USA')

account = BankAccount(10000)
account1.add_user(user1)
account1.add_user(user3)

account2 = BankAccount(402)
account2.add_user(user2)
account2.add_user(user3)
```

Now, I want to define a function access in my `BankAccount` class which returns `True` if the user has access to that account. For example:

```
account1.access(user3)
>> True
```

But I don't quite understand how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `in` operator to test if the given user is in the account's `users` list:

```
def access(self, user):
    return user in self.users
```

Comment: I tried that but then I got the following error: **TypeError: argument of type 'User' is not iterable**

Comment: Can you updated your question with the code of your `Account.add_user` method? It seems highly likely that your `add_user` method simply assigns the given user to `self.users` rather than append to it as a list.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't appending. It's working now. Thank you